# how to recieve data from BLE in flutter between esp32 and flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to receive data packets from ESP32 and the ESP32 is working properly(I tested it using BLE scanner) but when I want to receive data on my own app, i receive the following data:

```
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is ESP32 GET NOTI FROM DEVICE
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is
```

where "ESP32 GET NOTI FROM DEVICE" is the name of ESP32 bluetooth device

and this is not what I should receive...
the data I want to get is either 0 or 1, so the value I got is not really suitable and actually I received this:

```
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is [69, 83, 80, 51, 50, 32, 71, 69, 84, 32, 78, 79, 84, 73, 32, 70, 82, 79, 77, 32, 68, 69, 86, 73, 67, 69]
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is [0, 0]
I/flutter (23252): The received Value is [0]
```

then I converted it to the top one.

the code which receives the data is:

```
  writeDataAndWaitForRespond() async {
    writeData("A 300 300 300");
    List<BluetoothService> services = await targetDevice.discoverServices();
    print("////////////////We're here, listening to Hive...");
    services.forEach((service) async {
      var characteristics = service.characteristics;
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
          List<int> value = await c.read();
          print("We're here, listening to hive...");
          String stringValue = new String.fromCharCodes(value);
          print("The received Value is $stringValue");
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

when I send "A 300 300 300" to the device, it'll send either 1 or 0 in return.
is this the write code?? the library I'm using is flutter_blue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [flutter_blue](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue) package. I checked the flutter_ble package, it looks like an old fork. There is also an example project.

In relation to the topic. You need to scan for a device, then you can discover the target characteristic service. After that you have to register to the specific characteristics.

If it is a ESP32, do you use it in transparent bridge mode? So in this case, you generally have service for rx and tx. I've also an example, which might help you out: https://github.com/KevinRohn/flutter_ble_data_handler/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: sorry, I'm using flutter_blue that was a typing mistake, everything is working fine and when I send something from ESP32 I can receive it on flutter app but it is always the text in the question, thank you.